# Creation of second Active Directory Forest based on configuration created beforehand

Tags: active-directory, windows-domain, administration, windows-server-2022

I'm considering use of dual forest configuration where second domain (forest) will be hardened version of the first domain with one-side trust. And I wonder if there is a way to avoid most of double work when creating second forest.

I have the freedom of working on blank card so there are no problems with services, old standards, etc. But I'd like to move as many of configuration elements as possible (hardening GPOs, initial GPOs, user list) and modify them to more strict requirements in second forest.

Options I'm aware of for now:

1. Create additional DC, cut it from network. Rename forest and connect it back using one-side trust. It appears as possibly best option considering my carte blanche situation (I can install any problematic services after cloning).
   a) Are there any additional hooks apart from checklist in ["How Domain Rename Works"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc738208(v=ws.10)) on learn.microsoft?
   b) Is there a checklist of WS2022 built-in services that won't work after such operation?
2. Create new domain. Migrate users and GPOs. What are the things I miss out in such process?
3. Clone DC - not applicable (can't clone DC without high risk)

Purpose of such action would be to save myself double work with hardening and initial configuration GPOs which would be similar in both domains. I'd like to create them once and then clone them to avoid any omissions.

4. Is there a way to mass edit GPOs during migration or on existing? Ideal option would be to export them to csv or similar file, edit them en masse and import to new domain. Basic GPO interface is really clumsy for mass work as you have to click on every GPO and then click through all the options.